# How to get the details on backend nodejs with the GET request in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I am unable to fetch the query parameters of frontend GET request, on the backend side.
I tried using url and query. I need to fetch the query on the nodejs side.
Kindly suggest a suitable method that would help me get the details on GET request using axios.

**code -**

**component.ts - angular file**

```
googleSearch(googleText){


let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('q', googleText.trueLocation);
       

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3003/seekSearchApi" , ({params:params}))
      .pipe(map(Response => Response))
    
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {

        this.writeItOutput = res;
        
        resolve(this.writeItOutput);

      });

    })
    
  

}
errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  return throwError(error.message || 'server Error');
}
}
```

**server.js- express file**

```
app.use('/seekSearchApi', require('./server/nodejs-serverapi'));
```

**applicationserver.js - nodejs file**

```
function seekSearchApi(req,res) { 

var query = require('url').parse(req.url,true).query;

console.log("req.query.q", query.q);  //no response

console.log("Inside seekSearchApi");

  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?',
    data: {
      api_key: "xxxx",
      q:query.q
      hl: "en",
      gl: "us",
      google_domain: "google.com"
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    res.send(stringify(response))
   
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out .

On node side.

**applicationserver.js**

```
function seekSearchApi(req,res) { 

var url_data = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_data.query;
var queryData= Object.assign({},query);
console.log("queryData = ", queryData);

  ::::
}
```